# Populate RecyclerView and CardView with ArrayList<String>

Tags: android, arraylist

I have a cardview with 2 textviews inside. The first textview displays the name of a contact and the second displays the phone number. I want to use an ArrayList to populate the recyclerview.

---

I'm still new to Android programming so I don't know how to implement RecyclerView or make an adapter that will alternate between name and number filling in the textview. How can I achieve this?

My CardView (card_row.xml)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="24sp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/text1"
        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

EDIT:
I made 2 arraylists, one for names and the other for numbers. Now I how do I populate the recyclerview?

Comment: change your data structure. either use 2 lists, or a list of object that has 2 fields. that'll be easier and make more sense.

Comment: @njzk2 how do i fill the recyclerview with the 2 arraylists

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK First make a inner class. This will be your adapter change all the id:

```
class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LibraryAdapter.MyViewHolder>{
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public LibraryAdapter(Context context){
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }


    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_exerciselibrary_fragment_singlerow,parent,false);
        MyViewHolder holder=new MyViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Exercises exercises = new Exercises(getActivity());
            ArrayList<String> arrayList1 = new ArrayList<String>();
            ArrayList<String> arrayList2 = new ArrayList<String>();

            holder.Name.setText(arrayList1.get(position));
            holder.PhoneNumber.setText(arrayList2.get(position));



    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return array.lenght;
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView Name, PhoneNumber;
        CardView card;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            PhoneNumber= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewPicLibrary);//change Here
            Name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewExerciseLibraryExerciseName);//change Here
            card= (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view_ex_lib);//change Here

            card.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //OnClick
                }
            });


        }


    }
}
```

I think this is all.

Comment: my card view is its own layout xml file. but i will report back.

Comment: to an extent but not thoroughly

Comment: First lern about the list view  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hzrGAZnMOMQ&list=PLonJJ3BVjZW6hYgvtkaWvwAVvOFB7fkLa this is a good tutorial you will find every thing here

Comment: like I said, I just want to see what coding the more difficult things will be like. Im reading a book on android development and its says to "get your feet wet" and then start learning.

Comment: that does not make sense. it does not even compile